# Cut off last characters from html paragraph with JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to cut off last 20 characters from a normal html paragraph with a classname which contains two words? For instance `<p class="sentence slice">Last twenty characters have to be chopped off!!!</p>`

I know there's a slice method in JS https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice but how to implement this onto the website?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are interested in using [`.slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice), all you need to do is this:

**JavaScript**

```
$("#clickme").click(function () {
    var text = $("p").text();
    text = (text.length > 20) ? text.slice(0,-20) : text;
    // important to check whether the text is longer than 20 characters
    $("p").text(text);  // update the text
})
```

**HTML**

```
<p>Lots and lots and lots and lots and lots of text12345678901234567890</p>
<button id="clickme">remove last 20 characters</button>
```

## [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/d2QQ3/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$("p.sentence.slice").text(function() {
    var text   = $(this).text(),
        length = text.length;

    if (length > 20)
        return text.substr(0, (length - 20));
    else return text;
});
```

Comment: I was going to warn you that this would fail for strings of less than 20 characters, but I guess you got it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are mentioning the following, let's assume that you don't know the actual name of the classes; you just know that the paragraph tag that you want to modify, definitely contains two classes.

> (...) with a classname which contains two words?

Using tymeJV's solution (using `substr`), the following will only modify a paragraph tag which contains exactly two classes, and its length (in characters) is greater than 20.

```
$('p').each(function () {
    var classes = $.trim($(this).attr('class'));
    var count = classes.split(' ');
    var text = $(this).text();

    if(count.length === 2 && text.length > 20)  {
        $(this).text(text.substr(0, (text.length - 20)));
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EP47z/